# Android Eclipse How to import ads only sub-framework from google play -services?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am developing a project using eclipse for now --i plan to upgrade my project to Android Studio--

but for now i want to use AdMob in Eclipse and i want only the jar from the google play services. jar
i managed to do this in Android Studio 
with :

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5'
```

but i cannot do the same with eclipse
is there any ready google-play-services-ads.jar ?